# Trim whitespace in between characters

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, ios7, xcode5

i just updated to ios 7 sdk, and I would like to trim/replace the whitespace between characters of a string whereby the numbers are taken out from ABAddressBook.

I have tried using the replace " " with "" code below, but this code doesnt seems to work in ios7 sdk, it works fine in ios 6 sdk by the way.

```
NSString *TrimmedNumberField = [self.numberField.text 
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

is there any other way I could do it in IOS 7?

**EDIT:**

It's a phone number type that I'm trying.

Input: `"+65 12 345 6789"`

The output i got from NSLog is `" 12 345 6789"`

I realized that when I added into NSDictionary and view it in NSLog, it appears that it contains a unix code representation of \u00a0 which is similar to the "dot in the middle" which is not equals to a fullstop.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I can not test this at the moment, but I do not see why this should work differently in iOS 6 and iOS 7. Please give a concrete example of input string, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: @MartinR I have added the input and output i got from NSLog.

Comment: I do not have access to a Mac at the moment and therefore cannot test any Objective-C code, but I really wonder how your code should transform "+65 12 345 6789" into " 12 345 6789".

Comment: I agree with Martin R, and in cases like this, it is a good idea to reduce the problem to a test: Declare a string variable, assign the test string, do the conversion, then verify the result. If it is OK, then your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: hi @Monolo, thanks. you're right. i created a string variable and did the replacement. it works just fine. but the case happens when i return the phone number which i get from phone book into textfield, I got this problem when i am about to do the conversion.

Comment: @mfl follow the below ans and make it correct. If it really helps.

Comment: hey all. thanks for the tip. those number were number got from ABAddressBook. thus some numbers contain the "dot in the middle" or simply unix code of \u00a0 when view it from NSDictionary. However, i have found the solution. thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743883/ios-7-contact-number-spaces-are-not-spaces)

```
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
```

// where @"." was created by typing **Option**+ **Spacebar**

The number is extracted from ABAddressbook.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the string and remove whitespace as long as there is any

```
NSString *someString = @"A string with   multiple spaces and    other whitespace.";

NSMutableString *mutableCopy = [someString mutableCopy];

// get first occurance of whitespace
NSRange range = [mutableCopy rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

// If there is a match for the whitespace ...
while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    // ... delete it
    [mutableCopy deleteCharactersInRange:range];
    // and get the next whitespace
    range = [mutableCopy rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
}

// no more whitespace. You can get back to an immutable string
someString = [mutableCopy copy];
```

The result with the string above is `Astringwithmultiplespacesandotherwhitespace.`

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
NSString *str = @"   untrimmed   string   ";
NSString *trimmed = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Add a comment why did you down vote my answer i need to know the reason...?

Comment: stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet removes only characters at the start and at the end of the string.

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
[yourString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

**[whitespaceCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/whitespaceCharacterSet)** Apple Documentation for iOS says

Returns an NSData object encoding the receiver in binary format.

- (NSData *)bitmapRepresentation
  Return Value
  An NSData object encoding the receiver in binary format.

Discussion
This format is suitable for saving to a file or otherwise transmitting or archiving.

A raw bitmap representation of a character set is a byte array of 2^16 bits (that is, 8192 bytes). The value of the bit at position n represents the presence in the character set of the character with decimal Unicode value n. To test for the presence of a character with decimal Unicode value n in a raw bitmap representation, use an expression such as the following:

So Try This

```
NSString *testString = @"  Eek! There are leading and trailing spaces  ";
NSString *trimmedString = [testString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                             [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet removes only characters at the start and at the end of the string.

Comment: I think NSArray* words = [yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString* nospacestring = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""]; might work

Comment: It seems that you mixed up the documentation of whitespaceCharacterSet and bitmapRepresentation.