# iOS 7 contact number spaces are not spaces

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

In my app I am trying to retrieve the list of contact's number and try to do operations on them. I realized that whenever I have added new contacts (after updating to iOS 7) the new contacts formatting has changed, as there are spacings in the newly added numbers.

Using the ordinary replace methods does not remove the spaces.

Are these really spaces or what are these ? my objective is to get back the 'space' free number.

for example, if the number is `1 818 323 323 323`, I want to get `1818323323323`

Comment: What are "ordinary replace methods"?

Comment: @mrueg probably the standard NSString stringByReplacing* methods

Answer (score 19):

I looked at this as not getting rid of 'spaces' but being left with *only* decimal characters. This code did that for me:

```
phoneNumberString = [[phoneNumberString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

This takes out **everything** that's not a number 0-9.

**Swift 4.1:**

```
phoneNumberString = phoneNumberString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
```

Comment: Brilliant this works for me, however this will remove the + from the number if you are interested in keeping the plus you will need to apply some logic to it.

Comment: AWESOME! This worked like a charm. Thankyou so much :D

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
NSString *cleaned = [[phoneNr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

This should work for any kind of space ([of which there are many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)). It may seem somewhat inefficient, but for phone numbers, this should be ok.

Comment: I was almost certain this approach would work after trying to replace @" " @" "(alt-space) and @"\u00a0", but this approach didn't work for me

Comment: Worked for me with the \U00a0 issue with regard to address book phone numbers

Comment: To get this to work in my Localizable.strings file, I had to use all caps: `\U00A0`

Answer (score 7):

Some iOS7 phone numbers are encoded with non-breaking space. Try this:

```
        NSString* stringFormatted = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@""];
```

Comment: didn't work for me :[

Answer (score 5):

After way too much string cleaning I finally found an answer after printing the CFStringRef straight from the Address Book.  Here's what's going on behind the scenes...

1. Add a contact in iOS7 and Apple stores this: (555).555-5555 (where . is actually U00A0 or &nbsp)
2. My app copies a contact's info in a CFStringRef from AddressBook (when NSLogged the . shows)
3. CFStringRef is cast into NSString (NSLog now shows 555\U00a0555-5555)

To remove the \U00A0 I tried 3 answers from this thread and [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithRange:(160,1)] which didn't work.  What finally worked was this line of code:

```
phoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
```

// where @"." was created by typing Option+Spacebar

Comment: This way wouldn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

Another (very flexible) option is to use a regular expression. This allows you to retain the + or any other characters you want to remain.

```
let numberFromAddressBook = "+1 818 323 323 323"

let cleanNumber = numberFromAddressBook.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9+]", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil)

"+1818323323323"
```

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest solution I'm using in my apps is:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *phoneNubmerCharacterSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+"];
[phoneNubmerCharacterSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
NSString* phoneString = [[phoneString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[phoneNubmerCharacterSet invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

No "if" logic, keeps the + in number, removes all kind of random unwanted characters

Comment: This worked perfectly since there can be many unwanted character like \u0000 etc.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small adjustment to the poster's answer in case someone wants to maintain the + at the begining of the number.

I made this small adjustment if you want to keep the plus after removing the spaces.

```
 Boolean shouldAddPlus = NO;

 if([[phoneNumber substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        shouldAddPlus = YES;
    }

 phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

 if(shouldAddPlus)
    phoneNumber = [base stringByAppendingString:phoneNumber];
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to replace the occurences with a valid space

```
NSString *clean = [dirty stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@" "];
```

So you dont loose the space and the user sees what sees in other apps.